# How do I create designer exceptions when a find fails to find an element?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'd like to make a custom error message when I fail to find an element...

```
if find(:xpath, '*[@id="broken_path"]/div/a') == nil #or false?
   raise 'designer error message'
end
```

Do I need to try and catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capybaras `find` either returns the element or raises an exception.  To catch that you'd need to use rescue

```
def find_my_element
  find(:xpath, '*[@id="broken_path"]/div/a')
rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
  raise 'designer error message'
end
```

Note that if you call a method like this inside a `within` block (or any other synchronized Capybara block) it may defeat some of the waiting/retrying behavior since Capybara expects to see the ElementNotFound error.  You may be better off registering your own selector which allows you to specify your own description which will get returned in the message of the Capybara::ElementNotFound (See - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L67 - for the Capybara provided selectors as examples)

```
Capybara.add_selector(:my_selector) do
  xpath { |_unused| '*[@id="broken_path"]/div/a' }
  # could also be written as
  # css { |_unused| '#broken_path div a' }
  describe do |_options|
    "my description"
  end
end

find(:my_selector)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make your own exception class:

```
class MyFancyException < StandardError
end
```

Then you can `raise` it:

```
raise MyFancyException, "Fancy error message"
```

You don't need `try`/`catch` in Ruby. You use `rescue`:

```
def example
  do_stuff
rescue MyFancyException => e
  # e contains exception with message
end
```

Comment: How do I prevent find from raising the default exception first"

Comment: You'll have to `rescue` that exception and re-raise your own.